# Google drive unable to share

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs

I cannot share on my google drive. I've tried all the usual stuff (turning it off and on again, clearing cashe, cookies etc.), and all I get is the message

```
Sorry, sharing is unavailable at this time. Please try again later.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Clearing cookies and browsing history fixed this for me.

Answer (score 2):

For the Google doc giving this error, **simply closing its web browser tab then reopening it** (in the same browser including profile) **cleared up this error & others** in my fix result P2IK6O(internal id) of **my 1 of 1 case so far of this seemingly very rare error**, a solution inspired by the other 3 answers on this page and suggesting this was from some rare bug in Chrome and/or Google doc/Drive sharing.

Answer (score 1):

For sure it is something to do with browser settings, I would suggest upload your docs via laptop or desktop and you can later share it from mobile device. This is not the actual solution but a work around. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Try with another browser to see if it works.

if YES:
clear all the cookies and history of the browser you're using now and check again.

if NO:
something might be wrong with your google account settings. (Try another account on the same computer.)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried opening the same link using Incognito, and that worked.

Google also recommends that you clear your browser data, this can be done here:  chrome://settings/clearBrowserData

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you created the folder (that you wanna share) inside "Shared" tab. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I logged out of Google Drive and logged back in, and this resolved the issue for me.